# How to bind title from database for dropdown list with dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I bind the title from database for dropdown list with dynamically?

```
attr("title", data[i].Title)
```

I expect the output in below format when I mouseover on dropdown list :

```
title: { Apple, Mango }
```

Answer (score 0):

If `data[i].Title` is `"Apple,Mango"` then you can directly bind  like this:

```
attr("title", '{' + data[i].Title + '}')
```

Or if `data[i].Title` is `"Apple/Mango"` then you need to split the `data[i].Title` like this:

```
var title = data[i].Title.split('/')
attr("title", '{' + title + '}')
```